# Spring AuditorAware set createdBy manually

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data, spring-annotations

In my repository, I have fields, which are annotated with `@CreatedBy` and `@CreationTimestamp`. I'm using **spring-security** for authentication. Everything works, the fields in DB are filled with the correct *username* and *creationTimestamp*. But sometimes I need to set the *created* column myself, I need to override the `@CreatedBy` annotation. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

User id can be set by manually using below ways:

```
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    //retrieve userid here and set it.
    String userUid =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    setCreatedBy(userUid);
}

@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
    //retrieve userid here and set it.
    String userUid =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    setUpdatedBy(userUid);
}
```

Comment: Well the problem with this is, that the userId is different every time. @PrePersist takes no parameters in. How to I pass a parameter to it?